# The problem with multiplication and return

Tags: javascript

I can't figure it out, for example the following code:

```js
let baseMoney
  , min   = 3
  , max   = 10
  , price = 100
  ;
$('.cnt samp').click(function() {
  let self = $(this),
    prices = $('.price');
  if (!baseMoney) {
    baseMoney = price;
  }
  if (!self.hasClass('act')) {
    if (max > $('.act').length) {
      self.addClass('act');
    }
    if (max <= $('.act').length) {
      $('.cnt samp:not(.act)').addClass('disable');
    }
  } else {
    $('.cnt samp:not(.act)').removeClass('disable');
    self.removeClass('act');
  }
  if (min < $('.act').length) {
    price = parseFloat(baseMoney) * parseFloat($('.act').length - min);
    prices.text(price.toFixed(2));
  } else {
    prices.text(baseMoney.toFixed(2));
  }
});
```

```css
.act {
  background : rgb(0 201 34 / 80%)!important;
  }
.grid {
  display         : inline-flex;
  align-items     : center;
  justify-content : center;
  width           : 35px;
  height          : 35px;
  background      : #000;
  margin          : 5px;
  cursor          : pointer;
  color           : white;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cnt">
  <p class="prices">
    Цена:
    <span class="price">100.00</span>
    RUB
  </p>
  <samp class="grid">0</samp><samp class="grid">1</samp>
  <samp class="grid">2</samp><samp class="grid">3</samp>
  <samp class="grid">4</samp><samp class="grid">5</samp>
  <samp class="grid">6</samp><samp class="grid">7</samp>
  <samp class="grid">8</samp><samp class="grid">9</samp>
  <samp class="grid">10</samp><samp class="grid">11</samp>
  <samp class="grid">12</samp><samp class="grid">13</samp>
  <samp class="grid">14</samp><samp class="grid">15</samp>
  <samp class="grid">16</samp><samp class="grid">17</samp>
  <samp class="grid">18</samp><samp class="grid">19</samp>
  <samp class="grid">20</samp>
</div>
```

I need that when selecting elements, if more than `min` is already selected, the number starts multiplying by itself.

That is, for example, there is `100`, `4` is chosen, there will be `200`, `5` will be chosen, there will be `400`, `6` will be chosen, there will be `800`, etc.

But, it is also necessary to decrease, if the choice is removed, it was `6`, `1` was removed, it became `5`, then it will be `400`.

How can this be done?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask / https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example / https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: I don't see why this doesn't do what you want. The calculation uses the current number of selected elements every time, so if you remove a choice it should reduce the price.

Comment: What is `$('.cnt samp')` ?

Comment: @Barmar, Wrong works. And it doesn't decrease. I don't know how to do it, that's why I wrote it.

Comment: @MisterJojo, What we click on.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: @Barmar, Did! In general, it does not plow as it should!

Comment: I tried it, when I unclick items the price goes down.

Comment: @Barmar, Now read the question carefully and do it again! =)

Comment: You have some calculation errors, though. When I select 5 items the price is 200, not 400, and 6 items is 300.

Comment: it should be `price = baseMoney + (length - min) * 2 * baseMoney`

Comment: @Barmar, Nothing works, if you know the answer, then answer so that I choose it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the price double each time, you need to use powers of 2, not multiplication. You can use the `**` exponentiation operator.

There's no need to call `parseFloat()`, since these variables are all numbers.

```js
let baseMoney, min = 3, max = 10, price = 100;
$('.cnt samp').click(function() {
  let self = $(this), prices = $('.price');
  if (!baseMoney) {
    baseMoney = price;
  }
  if (!self.hasClass('act')) {
    if (max > $('.act').length) {
      self.addClass('act');
    }
    if (max <= $('.act').length) {
      $('.cnt samp:not(.act)').addClass('disable');
    }
  } else {
    $('.cnt samp:not(.act)').removeClass('disable');
    self.removeClass('act');
  }
  if (min < $('.act').length) {
    price = baseMoney * 2 ** ($('.act').length - min);
    prices.text(price.toFixed(2));
  } else {
    prices.text(baseMoney.toFixed(2));
  }
});
```

```css
.act{background:rgb(0 201 34 / 80%)!important;}
.grid{display:inline-flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;width:35px;height:35px;background:#000;margin:5px;cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cnt"><p class="prices">Цена: <span class="price">100.00</span> RUB</p> <samp class="grid">0</samp><samp class="grid">1</samp><samp class="grid">2</samp><samp class="grid">3</samp><samp class="grid">4</samp><samp class="grid">5</samp><samp class="grid">6</samp><samp class="grid">7</samp><samp class="grid">8</samp><samp class="grid">9</samp><samp class="grid">10</samp><samp class="grid">11</samp><samp class="grid">12</samp><samp class="grid">13</samp><samp class="grid">14</samp><samp class="grid">15</samp><samp class="grid">16</samp><samp class="grid">17</samp><samp class="grid">18</samp><samp class="grid">19</samp><samp class="grid">20</samp></div>
```

Comment: Wrong works. Every choice must be multiplied by itself.

Comment: Now I see, it's an exponent, not multiplication.

Comment: Is it really fixable at all?

Comment: I've updated the answer.